# Large source ImageView animation

Tags: android, animation, view, imageview

What's the best image file format for Android in terms of memory? PNG is recommended for iOS as xCode does some magic with it.. Is it the same for Android?

I'm currently developing a big app with multiple animations going on (sliding in screens, fading etc etc). All works well so far! However I have noticed the view animation where the view contains an ImageView with a (quite large) PNG as the source is a bit laggy.

Obviously I can make the PNG smaller, but is there anything extra I can do to reduce the amount of memory the ImageView takes up/makes the animation smooth? I know PNG has a much larger file size than JPEG, but I can't see this being a problem, the JPEG or PNG (I assume) is eventually stored as an array of colours, so they would both take up the same memory. PNG is probably better for loading due to less cycles uncompressing. Again I only assume, my knowledge of image file formats is null.

Alternatively is there anything else causing the lag? Is the bitmap scaled to fit the view each onDraw() during the animation so should I scale the bitmap in code before giving it to the ImageView?

Thanks,

Comment: Images are stored in memory always as Bitmaps. The file format on the file system does not matter afaik. To save memory make sure you prescale your images if they are larger than they appear on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formats supported by Android are: PNG, JPG and GIF (also 9.png).
The recomendated is PNG as said in [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap)

All of them are stored in memory as a Bitmap, so the most important thing is the color deph, like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon, options);
```

More info: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602282/android-is-decreasing-size-of-png-files-have-some-effect-to-resulted-bitmap-in)

Answer (score 0):

and add (after honeycomb):

```
<application 
    android:largeHeap="true"
    ...
```

to your **manifest file** :=)

**thanks to my dear friend :)**